# What is the rationale for the `/usr` directory?

Tags: filesystem, history-of-ubuntu

What is the rationale for the "unix system resources", or `/usr` directory, as described [here](http://wiki.debian.org/FilesystemHierarchyStandard), which duplicates many of the directory names under the root directory `/`?

My purpose: I'm installing Oracle JDK for the umpteenth time and decided this time to just put it under `/home/user` and I'm just reading around a bit to see if it is a bad idea on a single user machine.

Comment: Your home directory is a perfect place for installing third-party software as non-root.

Comment: ...the sad realization because you thought `/usr` meant a hidden "user" directory for so many years...

Comment: I seriously thought it was "user" this whole time. Like user binaries

Comment: @TannerBabcock I think it is. At least I think /usr/bin is meant to be where system wide binaries are installed that are not considered system essential.

Answer (score 264, accepted):

There are the short version and the long version of your answer...

## History

**Short version:**

As your link already said, `/usr` is a place for *system-wide*, *read-only* files. So all your installed software goes there. It does not duplicate any names of `/` except `/bin` and `/lib`, but originally with a different purpose: `/bin` and `/lib` are only for binaries and libraries *required for booting*, while `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib` are for all the other executables and libraries. *(now please don't ask about `/sbin`, this is the *Short* Version after all)*

Nowadays, the distinction between required and not required for booting has diminished, since most modern distros, including Ubuntu, cannot properly boot without several files from `/usr`. And that's why there was a strong [movement towards merging](https://wiki.debian.org/UsrMerge) `/usr/bin` and `/bin`. Starting from Ubuntu 19.04 `/bin`, `/lib` (and `/sbin`) are just [symlinks to their `/usr` counterparts](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-announce/2018-November/001253.html), and since Ubuntu 20.04 they don't even exist anymore.

But maybe you are confusing `/usr` and `/usr/local`? Because yes, there is (and should be) a *lot* of duplicated directory names. More on that later...

**Long version:**

Back in the 70's, in Unix (yes, Unix, way before Linux), disks had little space (no hard drives yet!), and at a given point the system binaries grew too much in number and size to a point they would not fit a single disk, and developers had to split them across several media and thus create new mount points for them. `/bin` filesystem was full, so they installed the new binaries at... `/usr/bin`. And `/usr` was, at that time, their... **user** directory!

After this split happened, which is almost embarrassing and often told as a joke/lore, they started to create artificial justifications and criteria to decide what would go to `/bin` and what would go to `/usr/bin`. The informal rule was: "essential" stuff go to `/bin`, "the rest" goes to `/usr/bin`. Same with `/lib`. It was not long before `/usr` became crowded with system-related directories mixed with actual users' homes. Thus `/home` was born, to hold all user-related directories and keep `/usr` clean for "system stuff" only.

This was long before the [FHS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard) exist. When it was created, it embraced and formalized that current tradition and kept the name `/usr`, although at that time it already had nothing to do with "user" anymore. So yes, fancy names like "**U**NIX **S**ource **R**epository" or "**U**NIX **S**ystem **R**esources" are all made-up names, and it's too late to rename it anyway. But, as we've seen it, not too late to toss `/bin`, `/lib` and `/sbin` into it. So `/usr` is now the main "system" directory.

*"Ok, what about `/usr/sbin`?"*, you ask. Damn, I was hoping you had forgotten. Ok... `/usr/sbin` is for commands that can only be (or are only meaningful when) executed by the `root` user, like `mount` and `fdisk`.

*"But isn't that almost the same as `/bin`?"*. Yes, sure, but...

*"Wait, then why there is an `/sbin` too? That doesn't make any sense!"*. Well, that's because of... err... humm... hold on...

***Look, a 3-headed monkey behind you!***

Ok, hopefully, you got distracted enough. Moving on...

*If you think I'm cheating, yes, I am indeed. But so is the "official" answer:* "Essential commands that can only be executed by root and must be available before you even mount `/`." *What? Come on! Truth is: the line is indeed blurry, and there are lots of legacy names and paths that just "stuck" and now it is quite hard to get rid of.*

More on the [Case for the `/usr` merge](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/TheCaseForTheUsrMerge/), from `systemd` docs:

> The historical justification for a /bin, /sbin and /lib separate from /usr no longer applies today. They were split off to have selected tools on a faster hard disk (which was small, because it was more expensive) and to contain all the tools necessary to mount the slower /usr partition. Today, a separate /usr partition already must be mounted by the initramfs during early boot, thus making the justification for a split-off moot. In addition, a lot of tools in /bin and /sbin in the status quo already lost the ability to run without a pre-mounted /usr. There is no valid reason anymore to have the operating system spread over multiple hierarchies, it lost its purpose.

And an amazing reading about the `/usr` split and its rationale, by Rob Landley:

[Understanding the bin, sbin, usr/bin , usr/sbin split](http://lists.busybox.net/pipermail/busybox/2010-December/074114.html)

---

## Nowadays

Currently, regarding install directories, your the best way to understand is to think this way:

- `/usr` - all system-wide, read-only files installed by (or provided by) the OS
- `/usr/local` - system-wide, read-only files installed by the local administrator (usually, you). *And that's why most directory names from `/usr` are duplicated here.*
- `/opt` - an atrocity meant for system-wide, read-only *and self-contained* software. That is, software that does not split their files over `bin`, `lib`, `share`, `include` like well-behaved software should.
- `~/.local` - the per-user counterpart of `/usr/local`, that is: software installed by (and for) each user. Like `/usr`, it has its own `~/.local/share`, `~/.local/bin`, `~/.local/lib`.
- `~/.local/opt` - the per-user counterpart of `/opt`

**So where to install software?**

The above list is already half the answer of you Oracle JDK question, at least it gives several clues. The checklist to *"Where should I install software X?"* goes by:

- Is it a completely self-contained, single directory software, like Eclipse IDE and other downloaded java apps, and you want it to be available to all users? Then install in `/opt`
- Same as above, but you don't care about other users and I want to install for your user alone? Then install in `~/.local/opt`
- Its files split over multiple dirs, like `bin` and `share`, like traditional software compiled and installed with `./configure && make && sudo make install`, and should be available to all users? Then install in `/usr/local`
- Same as above, but for your user only? Then install in `~/.local`
- Software installed by the OS, or via package managers (like Software Center), and, most importantly, *which any local modification might be overwritten when update manager upgrades it to a new version*? It goes to `/usr`

**Notes:**

- This explains why default install prefix for compiled software is `/usr/local`, and why you should change it to `./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local` when installing software for your own user only
- You may have noticed that **all** above directories are *read-only* (except, of course, when you install/remove software). The writable files (like config files) usually go to `/etc` (for system-wide software) and `~/.config` (for per-user settings). Although many legacy software (and, unfortunately, some modern too) still use `~/.<software-name>`, cluttering your home folder root with dozens of hidden dirs and files.
- `~/.local` and `~/.config` are not part of the FHS specification. FHS does not deal with user's home folder. They are an attempt of [Freedesktop/XDG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freedesktop.org), another standard organization geared towards Desktop Environments (like Gnome, KDE, and Unity), to try to set some [conventions regarding the structure of the user's home](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html). Not all software adheres to it *(for example, distros have only recently included `~/.local/bin` in user's default  `$PATH`, and only if it exists)*, and no user is forced to follow it, but both gain many interoperability benefits if they do.

I hope this helps to clarify things a bit. Feel free to ask anything so I can improve the answer!

***(and I also hope purists don't kill me for such an extremely informal language and explanation. It was intentional, and it surely has many inaccuracies, but I do believe it's a good way to make a newcomer have a brief overview understanding about install directories rationales)***

Comment: You summed it up very concisely and yes, it's true- the complete answer is a much longer story than the above!

Comment: Why not? The same logic applies: an attacker may create an executable under the home or a subdirectory of its, named after a system command.

Comment: @ignis: if an attacker has access to create and modify files under a user's home, then that user is already completely compromised, and `$PATH` is irrelevant. The attacker can even change *that* via `~/.profile`, so your point is moot. `~/.local/bin` is as secure (or insecure, if you want) as `~/bin`, which is common practice in most distros. The idea that a user should not have *any* dir to keep and execute personal scripts in `$PATH` is absurd.

Comment: Thus, `~/bin` is as secure as `~/.profile`, and `$PATH` does not protect me from malware run by me (which has the permission to write in my own home). I did not know this file, I'm sorry. Thank you for the clarification, sorry for my previous comment.

Comment: The longer history it has, the more improvement/mess there is.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Any updates to the current version? 17.04?

Comment: This answer is like a journey! This man rules :)

Comment: @danfromisrael: no big news for 17.04 (or 2022): XDG standard is now more widely adopted and has more dirs in the spec, such as runtime and state, `/opt` is also more common, and there are the self-contained _snaps_, but the **Nowadays** section still remain true.