# How do I create a desktop entry to launch a Python script?

Tags: .desktop

I made my little Python app, but I can't launch the app using the desktop entry I created:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=MyApp
Version=0.1
Exec=/usr/share/MyApp/MyApp.py
Icon=/usr/share/MyApp/img/MyApp.png
Comment=Description......
Type=Application
Terminal=false
StartupNotify=false
Categories=Video;GTK;GNOME
```

The `/usr/share/MyApp` folder I made as root and the `MyApp.py` has executable properties.

Every time I double Click the `MyApp.desktop` the `MyApp.py` launch, display a systray icon, but it closes and make Ubuntu display a error message.

If I run the `MyApp.py` from terminal or double click on the `.py` file it runs normally, no crashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following text in your .desktop file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=/usr/share/MyApp/MyApp.py
Icon=/usr/share/MyApp/MyApp.py
Path=/usr/share/MyApp/
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Comment: I got an untrusted application launcher error?

Comment: I had to explicitly add 'python' to the Exec config, i.e: `Exec=python /usr/share/MyApp/MyApp.py`

Answer (score 15):

May I offer a few notes and improvements over the accepted answer?

- Manually installing software to `/usr/share` is ***strongly discouraged!!!*** That tree should be reserved for software installed by your package manager (Ubuntu Software Center, `apt`, etc). There is `usr/local/share` for that. Or, if you don't want to use `sudo`, you may install for your user only at `~/.local/share`. See https://askubuntu.com/a/135679/11015 for more information about software install directories.
- If you want to execute a `.desktop` file by double-clicking on it, in Nautilus or your Desktop, just make the `.desktop` file executable! Note that this is not required if you copy it to `/usr/share/applications` and launch it via Dash/Menu. Or, better: copy to `~/.local/share/applications` or at least `/usr/local/share/applications`, as suggested above.
- `Icon=/usr/share/MyApp/MyApp.py` makes no sense: a `.py` file is not a valid image, so it cannot be used as an icon. If you want to use the default python icon, use `/usr/share/pixmaps/python.xpm`
- The main difference between your `.desktop` file and the accepted answer is the `Path=/usr/share/MyApp/` statement. If *that* made your app work, it means your software *requires* the current directory to be the application directory. And that is a bad thing: your software should be able to run fine and find its data files regardless of current directory. (*hint: use python's `__file__`*)
- If your application is a GUI (ie, it has a window), then add `StartupNotify=true`. It will help the launcher identify its window when it is running.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should move your Python file to `/usr/local/bin` or `/bin`
and remove the `.py` at the end and add `#!/bin/python3` to first line of your python file then copy you icon to `/usr/share/pixmaps`
and add this in the `.desktop` file

```
Exec=<your file name which is in bin>
Icon=<your logo name without .png or xpm at back>
```