# Why is g++ installed at usr/bin and not in usr/local/bin

Tags: filesystem, g++

I'm trying to understand the file structure of Linux systems.(At least basic parts).

Now, according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/130186/what-is-the-rationale-for-the-usr-directory) answer, `/usr/local` - directory is for read-only files installed by the local administrator (usually, you). And that's why most directory names from `/usr` are duplicated here.

Here is my question -  I decided to install g++ compiler. So it is a program which will be installed by me (local admin). However, it has been installed on `usr/bin` instead of `usr/local/bin`. What is the reason for that?

**EDIT**

```
$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++

$ ll $(which g++)
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 7 Nis  8  2014 /usr/bin/g++ -> g++-4.8*
```

Comment: Please post the outputs of `which g++` and `ll $(which g++)` by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: @ByteCommander I editted it

Comment: How did you install g++ ?

Comment: sudo apt-get install g++ @solsTiCe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you install it.

Usually packages install most of their files under `/usr` only. Even if it's you, the *admin*, that installs the package.

"**installed by the admin**" means installed by **hand** i.e. without the package manager. This means either by **copying** files in `/usr/local` directly or via `make install` command.

But this is just a *recommendation* and the admin can do whatever she wants and install manually in `/usr` if she wishes too. These are just guidelines. Noone is there to enforce those rules.

Comment: thanks for info, so its installed on /usr/bin because of my way of installing it right?

Comment: @stackunderflow here's mine: `/usr/lib/hardening-wrapper/bin/g++`. Most will be installed under /usr.